# How to rerender component, using useEffect and useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to show a table in my react component, but i don't know how to use useEffect and useState to render table in first render.

My component js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const Projects = () => {
  const [tableData, setTableData] = React.useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzuKuSOUfd9IOsQobix0PnIRv28IB3uTx5KdpVoVeNe04g7QzXQeeCEbsHBxE5CYdEV8A/exec') //получение информации из API гугла
        .then((response) => response.json()) //изменения формата в JSON
        .then((response) => {
          //запись значения JSON в переменную tableData
          setTableData(response['smr'])    
          console.log('Response in useEffect:')
          console.log(response['smr'])     // data is OK
          console.log('tableData in useEffect:')
          console.log(tableData)           // data is undefined
        }) 
  }, []);     

  return (
    <div>
    {/* {tableData.map(item => {
      <div key={item.is}>
        {item.adress}
      </div>
    })} */}
    </div>
  )
  
}

export default Projects
```

and i also use Routing in index.js:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
            <App />
        </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
);
```

Comment: You need a _return_ statement inside the `map()` method: `return <div>...`

Comment: Also a common practice is just to set the initial array to an empty one so that map will not error -> `React.useState([])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that your request completes sucesssfully, you can conditionally render the component like this"

```
 return (
    <div>
    {tableData && tableData.map(item => 
      (<div key={item.is}>
        {item.adress}
      </div>)
    )}
    </div>
  )
```

This way, the component only renders when `tableData` is not falsey (ie null or undefined).

Answer (score 1):

useState in react is a function that marks the value as dirty and so it triggers the rerender, only on the next rerender the actual value is updated. That means that if you print the value before the component is rerendered it will print the old value.

You also want to initialize the state with an empty array otherwise it will error saying that `map` method doesn't exists in an undefined object.

```
  const [tableData, setTableData] = React.useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzuKuSOUfd9IOsQobix0PnIRv28IB3uTx5KdpVoVeNe04g7QzXQeeCEbsHBxE5CYdEV8A/exec') //получение информации из API гугла
        .then((response) => response.json()) //изменения формата в JSON
        .then((response) => {
          //запись значения JSON в переменную tableData
          setTableData(response['smr'])
          // tableData here has not yet changed the value so
          // it will print the initial value
        }) 
  }, []);     

  // if you want to print the values of tableData put a console log out of the useEffect

  return (
    <div>
     {tableData.map(item => 
      (<div key={item.is}>
        {item.adress}
      </div>)
    })
    </div>
  )
```